# Math notation in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm would like to create a formula I have, into Objective C code.

```
float loanP = ((interestRate/100/12) *loanAmount) /(1-(1+(interestRate/100/12))^- loanTens)
```

Is there some notation I should be using for the

```
^-loanTens
```

part?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

objective C has all the libraries and classes which were in C/C++.
We have some math classes to perform math functions.

import math.h file

which has math functions useful to you.

here you need power operation i think so.

this will be something like this

```
int a = pow(10,4);
```

have a look at the available functions in the math.h and make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use pow:

```
float loanP = ((interestRate/100/12) *loanAmount) / pow(1-(1+(interestRate/100/12)), -loanTens);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pow function or u can define value of `(1+(interestRate/100/12))^- loanTens` using your own code.

```
int value= 1 + (interestRate/100/12);
int total =1;
  for(int i =1;i<=loanTens;i++){
total = total*value;
}
float loanP = ((interestRate/100/12) *loanAmount) /(1-(1/total));
```

or second method:

```
float loanP = ((interestRate/100/12) *loanAmount) / (1 - 1/(pow((1+(interestRate/100/12)), loanTens)));
```